# C# how can I loop through all Elements of a List <string>

Tags: c#, string, list, object, foreach

I have the following problem. I have a list of strings and want to split these. After that, I want to give each Object Element a reference to an item of the List.

Example:

```
List<string> valueList = attr.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
```

This List has items like that:

```
name,string,age,int
```

For this example every Object needs to get 2 pieces of information, first the name (out of example: "name" or "age") and second the type (out of example: "string", "int").

Now I want to get an Object with this informations. So I created Objects and put these Objects into a List.

Example:

```
List<MyObject> listObjects = new List<MyObject>();
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < ValueList.Count; i++)
{
     MyObject object = new MyObject();

     if (ValueList.Any(s => s.StartsWith(modifier)) == true)
     {
          object.name = ValueList[i];
          object.type = ValueList[i + 1];
     }
     listObjects.Add(object);                          
}
```

But with my solution, I'm getting a *System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException*. My explanation for this would be the foreach but I don't know a technique on how to get every item of the List of strings and add these to objects. Also what a problem is that 1 item of the List should have 2 elements (name, type) but with my method, I'm going through the *foreach* for every element. Is there any better way to do it in C# .Net Framework?

Comment: You are splitting on a whitespace but your initial input is separated by commas

Comment: It was an example, so I meant that after the split the List<string> elements could look like that.

Comment: OK, about foreach, before anyone even invented it we used the normal _for_ loop for years

Comment: You loop through "item"; but there is no "item" in your code, but an "i"-Index. Modifier is not defined.

Comment: Also it is not clear what is that _readerValueArray_ and how many elemets it contains. This is probably the cause of your IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: I just posted snippets of the code so actually the i-index and the modifier are actually there.

Comment: @brstkr if you really want to be helped you should help us to understand your problem. Not exposing the _relevant_ parts of your problem is not very useful. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: Oh sorry I forget to change this as well, it should be "valueList" instead of "readerValueArray".

Comment: @brstrk. But the idea of your loop is not clear. You can also loop around all sorts of swiss cheese. You do two nested loops here, the foreach and the Any. Usually you end a loop (you end increasing i) if you reach the end of readerValueArray.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59448223/edit) your question so it actually shows the problem you are having because what you have posted doesn't.

Comment: change it to i+=2 rather than i++

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want something like this.

```
// Store your relevant keywords in a list of strings
List<string> datatypes = new List<string>{"string", "int"};

// Now loop over the ValueList using a normal for loop
// starting from the second elemend and skipping the next
for(int x = 1; x < ValueList.Count; x+=2)
{
    // Get the current element in the ValueList
    string current = ValueList[x];

    // Verify if it is present in the identifiers list
    if (datatypes.Contains(current)))
    {
        // Yes, then add the element before the current and the current to the MyObject list
        MyObject obj = new MyObject;
        obj.name = ValueList[x - 1];
        obj.type = current;
        listObjects.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me alot, but I have one question. So when I'm going to loop like this it only creates one Object instead of two (object with name="name" and type="string"). How can I solve this, is it because of the valueList.Count condition?

Comment: Are you sure that after the last string (int) there is no spaces or other whitespace character? Change this line to _string current = ValueList[x].Trim();_ also Contains is case sensitive (string is not equal to String)

Comment: Ok I added it to *string current* but there are no whitespaces after the last string. It creates the first object successfully (with the right elements) but the second object was not created.

Comment: Not sure where is the problem. I tried this code with your example input ("name,string,age,int") and everything works as expected. I suggest you to use the debugger and check step by step the flow of your code and the values of the variables involved